# python boto3 aws lambda filter by region name - no result

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I am writing aws lambda in python boto3 to filter by region name. The response doesn't have anything

Response: null
START RequestId: 9ede007d-92ba-4617-bb82-4abd658ef5c6 Version: $LATEST
Regions
ResponseMetadata
END RequestId: 9ede007d-92ba-4617-bb82-4abd658ef5c6

```
import json
import boto3
import pprint
from pprint import pprint


def lambda_handler(event, context):
      aws_mgmt_console = boto3.session.Session()
      ec2_console_resource = aws_mgmt_console.resource('ec2')
      ec2_console_client = aws_mgmt_console.resource('ec2')
      #pprint(ec2_console_resource.meta.client.describe_regions())
  
     filter_specific_region = {'Name':'region-name', 'Values':['us-east-1']}
 
     for each_item in ec2_console_resource.meta.client.describe_regions(Filters= 
           [filter_specific_region]):
           print(each_item)
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from the lambda handler. Just printing it.

Comment: Is it not suppose to print us-east-1?

Comment: It will probably show "us-east-1" in the lambda handler logs. But that won't be in the lambda response unless you `return` it.

Comment: Go through the lambda basics doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Comment: Thank You so much. I will go thru the links. Appreciate